# Expected a file name

Tags: c++

So basically, I was looking at this source code to try and edit it and learn from it, but I'm constantly getting an "Expected a file name" error (E0013) With any source code that I attempt to use... Error is on the first line (using scripts\codescripts\struct) "scripts"

```
#using scripts\codescripts\struct;

#using scripts\shared\callbacks_shared;
#using scripts\shared\system_shared;

#insert scripts\shared\shared.gsh;

#namespace clientids;

REGISTER_SYSTEM("clientids", &__init__, undefined)

function __init__()
{
    callback::on_start_gametype(&init);
    callback::on_connect(&on_player_connect);
    callback::on_spawned(&on_player_spawned);
}
```

Comment: This isn't C++... What language is it?

Comment: `#using`? What kind of C++ is that?

Comment: Is it C++/CLI? Please, edit your question to add information about what specific language and compiler are you using.

Comment: Its not c++, its GSC - a script language used by call of duty

Comment: I'm not familiar with any language that has `#using`, `#insert`, and `#namespace`. I have to guess it's some kind of scripting language. My best guesses are either the path on the first line is incorrect (e.g., it's a directory and should be a filename), or (2) paths must be marked some way (e.g., perhaps that should be `#using "scripts/codescripts/struct"`or `#using <scripts/codescripts/struct>`

Answer (score 1):

`scripts\codescripts\struct` 
 Extention of the file missing

It has to be like `#using <MyFile.dll>`
 Here .dll is file extention of the file MyFile .
Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab9swk4.aspx